# make CSS hover menu click rather than hover

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS/HTML menu with this CSS code:

```
#nav {
    background-color:#F36F25;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:35px;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    border-top:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#nav>li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    z-index:9999;
}
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    margin:0;
    background: #F36F25;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
}
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li a.active {
    color:#F36F25;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#nav li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
}
#nav li ul li {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    background-color: #F36F25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
    width:145px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color:#F36F25;
    border:1px solid #f36f25;
}
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

How can i ensure the onhover events stay but make the sub menus show on click rather than when the users hovers on the parent link?

i am happy to use Jquery or Javascript if needed but full css would be good if possible

Comment: post HTML and make fiddle

Comment: You have to use JS to handle click event. For your own good, research click events and fiddle around. If you want someone here to do the work for you and give you solved solution, you have to give html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can `:focus` instead of `:hover` like this 
update this code

or through js **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Chj/449/)**

```css
#nav li:focus ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you want to change display strategies when you `click` on your element. Let's suppose your element has a `selector`. In that case, you can define this event with jQuery:

```
$(selector).click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }
});
```

And you need to have some CSS for `.clicked` as well. Let us suppose your selector is `#foo`. Then you need rules like this:

```
#foo {
    /*Add some stuff*/
}

#foo.clicked {
    /*Add some stuff*/
}
```